# Custom scripts displaying in menu bar?

Tags: terminal, menu-bar

I am a Linux user considering switching to a Mac.

Currently I use Polybar and in it I have custom bash and python scripts that represent different information. For example

[image]

In polybar I can interact with the running script as clicking can be configured to give different inputs. For example

> [module/study]
> type = custom/script
>
> exec = /home/testing/yet.py main tail = true label =
> %output%
>
> click-left = /home/testing/yet.py
>
> pause click-right = /home/testing/yet.py stop
>
> click-middle = /home/testing/yet.py start

**Question:** Is there a way to achieve a similar functionality on MacOS?

Answer (score 0):

See github's search results for [mac menu bar scripts](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=mac+menu+bar+scripts&type=repositories). At the time of responding, the top result is [xbar](https://github.com/matryer/xbar).

> ## [xbar](https://xbarapp.com)
>
> Put the output from any script or program into your macOS Menu Bar (the BitBar reboot)
>
> [image: xbar on macOS]